# How do I install spotipy module?

Tags: python, module, installation, spotipy

I have tried installing spotipy to my anaconda environment and there are no module results when I search spotipy. I tried the following code and got a syntax error:

```
pip install spotipy
```

I also got an error message when I tried this:

```
easy_install spotipy
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Which error messages are you getting when using pip/easy_install?

Comment: I think you may want to enter that in a shell, not a python script

Answer (score 1):

Spotipy is now packaged and maintained for [Conda Forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/spotipy):

```
conda install -c conda-forge spotipy
```

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda has its own package manager and repository. You can search the one with the other using [the Anaconda equivalent of `pip`](https://conda.io/docs/index.html) which is included with most versions of Anaconda.

`conda search <module-name>`

In the case of `spotipy`, you'd install it using

`conda install spotipy`

See [this page for details](https://anaconda.org/jkroes/spotipy).

Answer (score 0):

I found a conda install of spotipy version 2.4.4 in [Anaconda's packages](https://anaconda.org/jkroes/spotipy).

`conda install -c jkroes spotipy`

However, I was able to `pip install spotipy` in my terminal, then `import spotipy` in my Jupyter notebook which runs via Anaconda. So far the library has been working as expected.